# Redirect arbitrary request to directory to particular page in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect

That title isn't very descriptive, but I couldn't figure out how to phrase my question very well. What I'm trying to do is use a single page to interpret multiple URLs. Here's an example: `[domain]/name-of-question.aspx` is clearly not a file on the site's server, and yet the server acts like it is. This behavior makes pages much more readable and more easily bookmark-able.
My vision for the solution is to be able to have to server redirect a request to a certain directory to a particular page, whilst appending the name of the page requested to the page as a URL parameter. Here's what I mean: `[domain]/questions/name-of-question` redirects to `[domain]/question.aspx?page=name-of-question`.
This is how reddit does their self posts, I think, but they don't use ASP.Net or IIS.

Is this possible, and if so, how would one implement this behavior? If there's any code you write, please write it in C#, because I don't know VB.Net very well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use URL rewriting to accomplish this.

You have to create a rewrite rule that rewrites any requests to [domain]/questions/{1}
to [domain]/question.aspx?{1}

In ASP.NET you have the URL Rewriter module: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

The rule might look similar to this and is applied in the web.config file:

```
       <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RewriteUserFriendlyURL1" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="questions/(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="question.aspx?{R:1}" />
                <serverVariables>
                    <set name="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" value="image/png" />
                </serverVariables>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

EDIT: To change the content type, add the serverVariables section in the rewrite rule and authorise that variable to be set in IIS manager:

[image: server variables]
[image: allow server variable]

Comment: Thanks! I understand all but the `conditions` tags. Could you please explain those? To me, those tags seem to be contradictory, but I don't understand them, so I could be way off mark.

Comment: Those are for an edge case, if the incoming request matches an existing page on folder on disk, the request will not be rewritten and the existing page will be served instead. From your description they quite safe to be removed.

Comment: I have one more question:
How can I specify the document type to be an image? I'm using this to serve images, so I can't have the type be `text/html`. Thanks again!

Comment: You will need to add this after the action tag:                     <serverVariables>
                        <set name="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" value="image/png" />
                    </serverVariables>

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0+, then this might be worth a read, as ASP.NET Routing and URL Rewriting are not necessarily competing technologies, but potentially complementary features.

[URL Rewriting vs. ASP.NET Routing](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing)